# syntax error on conditional trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER  pm_session_one_Delete
      AFTER UPDATE
      ON pm_sessions
      FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN

          IF NEW.delete != OLD.delete THEN

               UPDATE pm
                 SET
                delete =  NEW.delete 

                WHERE
                NEW.id = pm.pm_session  ;

          END IF;

     END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

i get this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'delete = NEW.delete WHERE NEW.id = pm.pm_session ;' at line 11

Answer (score 1):

here,

```
 UPDATE pm
 SET
 `delete` =  NEW.delete
```

`DELETE` is a reserved keyword.

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: thanx , is there anyway around it ? if not i have to do it without trigger.

Comment: basically what are you trying to do?

Comment: when a pm session is getting deleted by one user i want to mark those pm belonging to that session to marked  , there's part of my app that i show latest pms and i don't want to pm with deleted session to show up there